# Can I simply PuTTy on a windows to route only certain (SOCKS5) traffic to a Anonymous VPN

Tags: vpn, putty, socks5

I have windows 7, and would like to take an anonymous VPN provider to route CERTAIN application's trafic through the VPN (for example utorrent via SOCKS5-setting).

This does not seem simple, requiring OpenVPN and a lot of setting.

Can't I just simply install puTTy, and make SSH tunnel to the anonymous VP ( I thinks some of the anonymous VPN provider allow this, or am I reading this incorrectly: https://proxy.sh/panel/announcements.php?id=125)

Please not that I mostly only have superficial knowledge about this.

Thanks

Comment: You can indeed setup puTTy to use a ssh tunnel on a port, say 8080, and set the application proxy settings to localhost:8080